# MYSQL Query not displaying properly

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables I am pulling information from (This is a database of the NFL). One table named "team" and another named "schedules". Within schedules I have 2 foriegn keys - "team_id" and "opponent_id" which both reference "team_id" in the team table.

I would like my query to display a "HOME TEAM" and "AWAY TEAM" with a "WEEK NUMBER" (attribute of schedules).

So far I have this query which works properly but will not display in one table without erroring:

```
SELECT t.team_name 'HOME TEAM', s.week_number 'WEEK'
FROM team t, schedules s
WHERE t.team_id = s.team_id;

SELECT t.team_name 'AWAY TEAM'
FROM team t, schedules s
WHERE t.team_id = s.opponent_id;
```

I have tried subquerying this second select statement but receieve and error saying that it will return more than one row.

How can I go about fixing this. I dont need an actual "answer" but am looking for some pointers. This isn't "homework" but is a project that I am working on for class... Just being honest haha.

Thank you and if you need more info I will be glad to give it -> just not sure how much you'll need in order to help me.

EDIT: I'd like to thank PM 77-1 for the help

Here's my final statement

```
SELECT t.team_name 'HOME TEAM',te.team_name 'AWAY TEAM', sc.week_number 'WEEK #'
FROM schedules sc 
JOIN team t ON t.team_id = sc.team_id
JOIN team te ON te.team_id = sc.opponent_id;
```

Comment: You need double `JOIN`. Is it enough of a hint?

Comment: Thank PM 77-1... I'll give it a shot! As you can tell I'm new to this so thanks for helping me out